# Determine if i18n is enabled for a JCR Property

Tags: properties, internationalization, jcr, magnolia

How to access the corresponding FieldDefinition, if I have only the jcr property name at hand.
Is there any desired functionality,like find a field definition by a jcr property name ? If not, how would I access configured field definitions in java code ?

Scenario : I need to determine, if a given jcr property name was configured to be an i18n-capable field in definition ?

Comment: Do you have access to info.magnolia.ui.form.definition.FormDefinition ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you can never be sure if property was configured to be i18n-able (or have any other trait) at the time it was last edited as definition might have changes since.

However to achieve what you want (obtain the definition), what you need to do is:

1. get a parent node of the property in question,
2. get value of it's `mgnl:template` property. That's your `templateId`,
3. use the `templateId` to obtain template from the registry,
4. read value of dialog property of the template, that's your `dialogId`
5. use the `dialogId` to obtain dialog from the registry
6. scan tabs in the dialog to find property definition with name of the jcr property you have started with